# React Native: render to the same screen with diferent params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What I want is to render the same screen with different params, if I use [push](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#push) action from react-navigation, this replaces all screens with the same params data on the other hand If I use replace I lost the navigation history. user flow:

- product details screen(this screen receive product ID)
- got to the similar products and tab on a product, this open a product details screen again with the new ID info
- Each screen must keep the information rendered with specific id

stack:

```bash
- product-detail-screen(ID)
  |_ tab on similar product
    |_ product-detail-screen(ID)
       |_ tab on similar product
         |_ product-detail-screen(ID)
```

Comment: did you solve it? if so, how did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass parameters to from the screen your in to screen your navigating to , in your case the parameter is id

when navigating send params like below

onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('ProductDetailsScreen',{id:id})}

receive params in next screen

const { id }=route.params;

use this id with your request

for more info read this doc about passing params in react navigation

`https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/`

Comment: This is fine, the problem is that all the ProductDetailScreen are kept with the same information from the last request instead of each one being kept with its own information from the request that was made when it was created.

Comment: can you attach code of both screens ? better attach it to question body